# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.DataSet' to 'string'

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

The below code is the web method (is the most common one as you can see it everywhere), but i keep getting the error from the title. I am at the beginning with .NET, so if anyone can point me into the right direction , please do so.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySQLconn"].ConnectionString);

[WebMethod(Description = "Select Customers")]
    public string GetVersionofSelectedCustomer(string versionEmail)
    {

        string select = "SELECT version FROM customer WHERE EMAIL = '" + versionEmail + "'";
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, myConnection);

        DataSet custDS = new DataSet();            
        //adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
        adapter.Fill(custDS, "Customers");

        return custDS;

    }
```

connection is defined in the Web.config (local connection) and **return custDS;** is where it fails.

Comment: Why are you returning a DataSet, maybe you can return a JSON response with the customers list in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of your function is `string` and you are trying to return a `DataSet` object. You can try like this:

```
public DataSet GetVersionofSelectedCustomer(string versionEmail)
{
     string select = "SELECT version FROM customer WHERE EMAIL = '" + versionEmail + "'";
     SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, myConnection);

     DataSet custDS = new DataSet();            
     //adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
     adapter.Fill(custDS, "Customers");

     return custDS;

}
```

Comment: Uhmmm  i don't know why i didn't saw that, but thank you so much. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

You are returning dataset so you should use return type as `Dataset`

```
public Dataset GetVersionofSelectedCustomer(string versionEmail)
{
    //add your code to return dataset
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature returns a string, but you are returning a DataSet - it's not clear exactly what you want to do here - possibly just change the signature to return a dataset?